# Hibernate Equivalent in eclipse link hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = validate

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I am defining the sql schema manually and using JPA 2.0 on top of it to use the schema. I am not allowing JPA to genarte/create andy schema for my application. 
While doing so i was using hibernate befor in wich the property as mentioned below

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
```

used to validate if the Table definition is valid accoridng to the JPA defined and if not the app server did not come up when it finds a mismatch between teh table and JPA.

Now i am moving to eclipse link and i have the

```
<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none" />
```

so Eclipse link is again not generating any schema, but there doesnt seem to be an equivalent of validation which we have in hibernate.

If my JPA has an extra colum defined and the table doesn't then also the web app comes up fine , Its only when the first insert happens for the table that the validation fails and throws an exception as shown .

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: 'OTHERNAME' is not a column in table or VTI 'APP.BSREQUEST'.
```

How can i make the web app persistence check and validate if things are correct during startup and not wait for when the first insert / delete happens.

Is there a equivalent to 
     in eclipse link i can use.

I tried using this but this doesnt help, the validation still occurs during first persit/delete operation.

```
<property name="eclipselink.orm.validate.schema" value="true"/>
```

Any one has an good idea on this ?

Answer (score 1):

At runtime, EclipseLink doesn't read database metadata. The eclipselink.orm.validate.schema property you enabled turns on XML schema validation for the JPA orm.xml file.

For excellent design time mapping/schema/Java validation you can use the JPA tooling (the [Dali Java Persistence tools](http://eclipse.org/webtools/dali/)) that ship as part of the [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) distribution and the [Oracle Enterprise Pack for Eclipse](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/overview/index.html).

Dali will tell you if you are mapping to a non-existant column and provides both integrated schema code completion and rich editors that you can use to correct errors.

Comment: Good point on the `eclipselink.orm.validate.schema` property. But Dali is really not a good alternative. You rarely have access to the production DB. The purpose of validating the schema up-front is to be able to prevent an application from launching itself and immediately see that the schema is not up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

There is no persistence unit property, but EclipseLink does support this through the IntegrityChecker.  This can be enabled through a SessionCustomizer.